# Mysql - Inserting multiple values into empty column of existing table without specifying all "where" conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I have a table in MySQL and I have append a new column to it with emtpy fields.

Now I am wondering if there is a possibility to append multiple rows to only this specific column without specifying the "where" condition for each row because there are many entries I wanted to so

I have something like this

```
INSERT INTO table.name
(`column.name`) VALUES
(2,
3,
1,
2,
0);
```

So that for the first row all values for each column stay the same but the value 2 will be appended to that corresponding empty column, for the 2nd row the value 3 will be attached and so on.

So I wanted to add for ALL rows a corresponding value in this new column. So the first value is for the first row, the second value of this new column for the 2nd row and so on

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No not like that, but can you identify the rows uniquely that need a change? Tell us what makes you want to amend the column in these specific rows

Comment: You're looking for an `UPDATE` not an `INSERT`. But there is no "first" or "second" row in a table, it is unordered. So you'll need some other criteria to identify which row gets which value.

Comment: I wanted to add for ALL rows a corresponding value in this new column.
 So the first value is for the first row, the second value of this new column for the 2nd row and so on

Comment: Is the value derived from any of the other columns in that row?

Comment: no sadly not ...

Comment: @Shuzo *So the first value is for the first row, the second value of this new column for the 2nd row and so on* As [sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit) tells there is not "first" or "second" in a table - table is unordered heap. You must specify some ordering by an expression which provides rows uniqueness for these terms make sense. For example, sorting by autoincremented column... then you must provide the list of the values with additional column which matches this sorting expression value or the number of the row in sorted rows - this makes UPDATE possible.